# find children while moving upwards in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

This can be sound little confusing but here it is.
What i want is to find the children(OF CLASS PARENT )  when user clicks on class target.
**Important:**  I am not aware of children class & child inside html structure.Target class can be after 'blah' like in first case OR can be directly after children like in second case.

**Information available:** class "PARENt" and $(this) [class target] 
**Find:** Children(ID) of class PARENT (you cannot use class **.children**)

```
<div class="parent">
<div class="children" id="1">
   <div class="blah">
      <div class="target">TARGET</div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="children" id="2">
   <div class="target">TARGET</div>
</div>
<div class="children" id="3">
   <div class="blah">
      <div class="target">TARGET</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### Example:

Clicking Target 1 would produce: ID = 1

Clicking Target 2 would produce: ID = 2

Clicking Target 3 would produce: ID = 3

Comment: `.target` has no children - if you mean `.children` class then please reword your question as it's not really clear what you are trying to do

Comment: If you don't know `children` class then how can you differentiate which element is "children"?

Comment: `$(this).closest('.parent').children('.children')` perhaps.

Comment: Its confusing. i need to find class  "PARENT" children. @RejithRKrishnan you cannot use '.children'

Comment: It's a confusing question. What do you want to access?

Comment: Then use just `$(this).closest('.parent').children()`

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: My answer does exactly what you want. Check my third edit and demo. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find only ONE ID use:

```
$('.target').click(function() {
  var found = false;
  var parent;
  var previous;
  while(!found) {
    if (previous) {
      parent = previous.parent();
    } else {
      parent = $(this).parent();
    }

    if (parent.hasClass('parent')) {
      found = previous;
    }
    previous = parent;
  }

  console.log(found.attr('id'));
});
```

[Demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/kLr19gk8/2/)

Comment: Please read the question again , when user clicks on target find the children id.

Comment: Daniel posted this 2 minutes before your edited in the id's.

Comment: Sorry ,but the final edit has been made m you can check the end.I dont want all the ids , the particular id.

Answer (score 1):

#### To literally answer your question:

`$(".parent *")` will give you **ALL** of the children of `.parent` no matter how many layers deep

#### To practically answer your question:

Limit possible elements, classes, IDs, etc.

`$(".parent div, .parent span, .parent .child ...etc")`

You can also grab only the immediate children of an element or set of elements by using the `>` CSS selector:

`$(".parent > *")` for example, will give you ALL of the immediate children of `.parent`

#### In the context of your problem

```
$(".target").on("click", function () {
  $(this).closest(".parent").children();
  // OR
  $(this).closest(".parent").find("*");
});
```

#### To get the specific ID

Given your current DOM structure...

```
$(".target").on("click", function () {
  var id = $(this).closest("[id]").attr("id");
  console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: Sorry ,but the final edit has been made  you can check .

Comment: @wordpressuser Updated to grab single ID

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.parentsUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/) to get the set of all parents up to (but not including) `.parent`. Then get the last element of this to get the child of the parent.

```js
$(".target").click(function() {
  var child = $(this).parentsUntil(".parent").last();
  console.log(child.attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children" id="1">
    <div class="blah">
      <div class="target">TARGET</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="children" id="2">
    <div class="target">TARGET</div>
  </div>
  <div class="children" id="3">
    <div class="blah">
      <div class="target">TARGET</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another